# x86 Assembly Lowercase unhandled exception

Tags: c, x86, access-violation, inline-assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [x86 convert to lower case assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656464/x86-convert-to-lower-case-assembly)

This program is to convert a 2d char array into lower case
Quickie Edit: I'm using Visual Studio 2010

```
int b_search (char list[100][20], int count, char* token)
{
__asm
{
    mov eax, 0          ; zero out the result
mov esi, list       ; move the list pointer to ESI
mov ebx, count      ; move the count into EBX
mov edi, token      ; move the token to search for into EDI 
MOV ecx, 0

LOWERCASE_TOKEN:            ;lowercase the token
OR [edi], 20h
INC ecx
CMP [edi+ecx],0
JNZ LOWERCASE_TOKEN
MOV ecx, 0
```

At my OR instruction, where I'm trying to change the register that contains the address to token into all lower case, I keep getting unhandled exception...access violation, and without the brackets nothing gets lowercased. Later in my code I have

```
LOWERCASE_ARRAY:        ;for(edi = 0, edi<ebx; edi++), loops through each name
CMP ecx, ebx
JGE COMPARE
INC ecx             ;ecx++
MOV edx, 0;         ;edx = 0

LOWERCASE_STRING:       ;while next char != 0, loop through each byte to convert to lower case
OR [esi+edx],20h    ;change to lower case
INC edx
CMP [esi+edx],0     ;if [esi+edx] not zero, loop again
JNZ LOWERCASE_STRING
JMP LOWERCASE_ARRAY ;jump back to start case change of next name
```

and the `OR` instruction there seems to work perfectly so I don't know why the first won't work. Also, I am trying to convert several strings.

After I finish one string, any ideas how I would go about going to the next string (as in `list[1][x]`, `list[2][x]`, etc...) I tried adding 20 as in `[esi+20*ecx+edi]` but that doesn't work. Can I get advice on how to proceed?

Comment: What compiler?  And did you consider first writing the function in C, then compiling it WITH OPTIMIZATIONS TURNED ON, then disassembling it, to see where the compiler pulls the arguments from, and comparing that to the disassembly of your assembly version?

Comment: Isn't `mov edi, token` just loading the address of your pointer, not the address the pointer contains? Should you use `mov edi, [token]` or some other form instead (perhaps `mov edi, token; mov edi, [edi]` or something) to actually load the pointer? Not knowing what compiler/assembler, it's hard to know how the code is interpreted, so examining a disassembly could certainly be helpful...

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010, x86. I forgot to include it earlier. I tried looking at a disassembly from c but I get the same exact error when I try to convert the token into lower case, needless to say that c program didn't work because I need case insensitivity.

Comment: You get the same unhandled exception when you run the C version of your code with no hand-assembled assembly?  Did you try to debug your algorithm from that perspective then?  If you have an algorithm that fails when written in C, it's not going to somehow work better if hand-coded in assembly.  Where's your C code version?

Comment: Also:  It's not clear how the function's parameters really are intended to be used.  If you know the size of list (100*20 bytes), what is 'count'?  And what the heck is 'token'?  I thought you're just trying to convert all uppercase letters in the array to lowercase... right?  Why would you need to "search" for a 'token'?

Comment: Good explanations of your problem are the key to getting good help.  (Also note that lengthy != good.)  And if you can't explain the problem, perhaps you don't even know enough to begin asking for help on a forum like this... try going to your teacher/professor.

Comment: I just didn't post the entire code because like you said lengthy is not good. In the end, this program is to search through `list` of `count` (e.g. 10) names and find the `token` name and return its position via `EAX`. However, the search is to be case insensitive which is why I'm converting everything to lower case, which I'm having trouble doing in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility:

If parameters of procedure `b_search` are stored as registers (register calling convention) then you override `list` pointer in your first asm line, because eax point to the `list` array:

```
mov eax, 0          ; zero out the result
```

Because:

```
mov esi, list       ; move the list pointer to ESI
```

should be converted to:

```
mov esi, eax
```

**Try to exchange first and second line to:**

```
mov esi, list       ; move the list pointer to ESI
mov eax, 0          ; zero out the result
```

Comment: Just tried it but it didn't change anything.

Comment: @gooberdope:  check your code with disassembler or debugger to see how it is looks.

Comment: @gooberdope: use `list*` declaration

Comment: When I debug my code, it says unhandled excepetion at whatever my EIP address is at and that there's an access violation at whatever my EDI address is at, although my EDI is pointing at my token (which happens to be "Jon") the EIP is pointing at some symbol that cannot be pasted here

Comment: The C portion of my program is given to me via template from my professor, so I'm not supposed to change it.

Comment: @gooberdope: your `list` variable is stored on the stack, so eax is probably only a index.

Comment: @gooberdope: pointer to `list` should be something like:  `[ESP + EAX]` or `[EBP + EAX]` or `[ESP + list]` or `[EBP + list]`

Comment: While I appreciate the help you're trying to give me, I'm not sure which of my problems it's solving. `TOKEN` is a name I'm searching for in `list`, but I'll face the `CMP` problems when I cross that bridge. My comparisons are supposed to be case-insensitive which is why I'm converting everything to lowercase. Is your advice trying to solve the problem where I advance from `list[0][0 to xx] to list[1][0 to xx]` etc... in where my lowercase conversion does actually work?

Comment: @gooberdope: to calcolate `list` pointer use somethin like: `lea  esi, esp + list`