# x86 convert to lower case assembly

Tags: c, x86, inline-assembly

This program is to convert a `char` pointer into lower case. I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

This is from another question, but much simpler to read and more direct to the point.

```
int b_search (char* token)
{
__asm
{
mov eax, 0          ; zero out the result
mov edi, [token]      ; move the token to search for into EDI 
MOV ecx, 0

LOWERCASE_TOKEN:            ;lowercase the token
OR [edi], 20h
INC ecx
CMP [edi+ecx],0
JNZ LOWERCASE_TOKEN
MOV ecx, 0
```

At my OR instruction, where I'm trying to change the register that contains the address to token into all lower case, I keep getting unhandled exception...access violation, and without the brackets nothing, I don't get errors but nothing gets lowercased. Any advice?
This is part of some bigger code from another question, but I broke it down because I needed this solution only.

Comment: Do you have to use assembly? There's already `tolower(char)`.

Comment: Advice? Debug your code. To begin with, are you getting the value of `token` in `edi`?

Comment: @chris its a homework problem, so probably.

Comment: @Wug, Yes, just can't be sure whether it's there for wanted speed, or because it's mandatory.

Comment: Yes I need to use assembly, I am debugging my code and the value of `EDI` is the starting address to`Token` which is why I'm incrementing `ECX` and adding it to `EDI.` I would travel byte by byte and convert everything to lowercase until I see `\0`. I see that in my `OR` I forgot to put `+ECX` but that tiny part is insignificant because I did do it in my actual code and I still get the error.

Comment: I think your second line should be `MOV edi, token` since `token` is a pointer so it contains the address of the first char.

Comment: @Lee You mean to exclude the brackets? I see the same thing debugging. EDI contains the same value and I still get an error preventing from turning an upper case to lower case.

Comment: @gooberdope - Your code works for me if you change the first line after LOWERCASE_TOKEN to `OR [edi + ecx], 20h`. Are you sure the buffer is null-terminated? Otherwise you may end up trying to access an invalid location. Other than that I would step through it in a debugger and watch the memory around `token` to see what is happening.

Comment: @Lee I changed it to what you said. Maybe the C part is where it's having trouble? The call to b_search is `char *token = "Jon"; id = b_search(list, i, token)`

Comment: "Jon" is probably on read-only memory. Try `char[] token = "Jon"` to initialize a char array on the stack, or allocate space and strcpy().

Comment: @ninjalij The C portion of this assignment was written by my professor. It's supposed to be run through the command prompt, but I just initialized it myself. I don't think I'm allowed to change it from a pointer to an array

Comment: @gooberdope - Your example passes three argument to `b_search`, but our function only has one parameter. Which is correct?

Comment: @Lee ah yes I did take off some parameters to make this code a little simpler. There is a `char list[100][20], i//is the count of how many strings are in this char, and then the token` I took ninjalj's advice and just changed the pointer to an array and it works. I'll complain to my professor about this when I can and get help from him.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can alter only the first char (or [edi], 20h) - the EDI does not increment.

EDIT: found [this thread](http://forums.codeguru.com/archive/index.php/t-365958.html) with workaround. Try using the 'dl' instead of al.

```
; move the token address to search for into EDI
; (not the *token, as would be with mov edi, [token])

mov edi, token      

LOWERCASE_TOKEN:            ;lowercase the token
  mov al, [edi]
  ; check for null-terminator here !
  cmp al, 0
  je GET_OUT
  or al, 20h
  mov dl, al
  mov [edi], dl
  inc edi
jmp LOWERCASE_TOKEN
GET_OUT:
```

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your code because I wanted to see if it does work, but it doesn't because the second i hit `mov [edi], al` my code yells at me. The value of `al` is indeed the lowercase, but for whatever reason I can't use [edi] that second time. The first time it went through, but the second `[edi]` and I got yelled at.

Comment: @gooberdope Your code yells at you? I think you should be more specific in programming contexts.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Like I said in my original question, I get an unhandled exception/access violation error. This is what my computer yells at me.

Comment: @ViktorLatypov Didn't work either. I'm always getting an unhandled exception at my EIP address and an access violation error at my EDI address

Answer (score 0):

I would load the data into a register, manipulate it there, then store the result back to memory.

```
int make_lower(char* token) {
    __asm {
        mov edi, token
        jmp short start_loop
    top_loop:   
        or al, 20h
        mov [edi], al
        inc edi
    start_loop:
        mov al, [edi]
        test al, al
        jnz top_loop
    }       
}
```

Note, however, that your conversion to upper-case is somewhat flawed. For example, if the input contains any control characters, it will change them to something else -- but they aren't upper case, and what it converts them to won't be lower case.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the OR operator like many others don't allow two memory or constant parameters. That means: The OR operator can only have following parameters:

```
OR register, memory
OR register, register
OR register, constant
```

The second problem is, that the OR has to store the result to a register, not to memory.
Thats why you get an access violation, when the brackets are set. If you remove the brackets, the parameters are ok, but you don't write your lowercase letter to memory, what you intend to do. So use another register, to copy the letter to, and then use OR.
For example:

```
mov eax, 0          ; zero out the result
mov edi, [token]      ; move the token to search for into EDI 
MOV ecx, 0
LOWERCASE_TOKEN:            ;lowercase the token
MOV ebx, [edi]        ;## Copy the value to another register ##
OR ebx, 20h         ;## and compare now the register and the memory ##    
MOV [edi], ebx      ;##Save back the result ##    
INC ecx    
CMP [edi+ecx],0    
JNZ LOWERCASE_TOKEN    
MOV ecx, 0
```

That should work^^