# Traverse 2d Array in Assembly x86

Tags: c, assembly, x86

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [x86 convert to lower case assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656464/x86-convert-to-lower-case-assembly)

In my problem, I have a 2d char array where I need to change everything to lowercase.

```
char list[100][20] = {{"ArtUro"}, {"Bryan"}, {"chris"}, {"David"}, {"Jon"}, {"Mark"}, {"shane"}, {"SIMON"}, {"Thomas"}, {"TONY"}};
```

And I have

```
int b_search (char list[100][20], int count, char* token)
{
__asm
{   
mov eax, 0          ; zero out the result
mov esi, list       ; move the list pointer to ESI
mov ebx, count      ; move the count into EBX
mov edi, token      ; move the token to search for into EDI 
MOV ecx, 0

LOWERCASE_ARRAY:        ;for(ecx = 0, ecx<ebx; ecx++), loops through each name
    CMP ecx, ebx
    JGE GET_OUT
    INC ecx             ;ecx++
    MOV edx, 0;         ;edx = 0

LOWERCASE_STRING:       ;while next char != 0, loop through each byte to convert to lower case
    OR [esi+edx],20h    ;change to lower case
    INC edx
    CMP [esi+edx],0     ;if [esi+edx] not zero, loop again
    JNZ LOWERCASE_STRING
    JMP LOWERCASE_ARRAY ;jump back to start case change of next name

GET_OUT:
```

I successfully turn ArtUro to lower case, but I cannot figure out how to traverse the array to the address of Bryan because I cannot scale by 20 and adding 20 leads my `ESI` to a whole other place.

Answer (score 0):

```
    LEA esi, [esi+20]
```

I put it between my two jump instructions in the second loop. Thanks to those who read my question though.